# Image under nav bar HTML CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

This site [here](http://www.vergecollective.com/) has an image under the navbar and it autoresponds to the dimensions of your browser. I would like to know:

1. How to get an image to look exactly like the one under the navbar. (I have an image I want to use I just don't how to get it into my site under the navbar)
2. How to get it to auto respond like their's does
3. How to make it so I can still add content to the page after that image in the banner area. Now I have it as the body background in CSS and that makes it so you can't add any content and be able to scroll.

Here is my code that I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Vector Games</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homecss.css">
    <head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">

            <div class="container">

            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">VectorGames</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arcade</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Puzzle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body{
    background-image: url("banner.png");
    width:100%;
}

.container{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    background: gray;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    position:fixed;
}

.logo{
    float:left;
    margin-left: -250px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
}

.nav{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/O8E0CBD.png) the image you are talking about?

Comment: I think he's talking about how the Menu resizes to a mobile layout when the dimensions are squeezed down. Not sure though.

Comment: Why don't you inspect the source?

Comment: No i am talking about the image under that... this one http://static1.squarespace.com/static/539f9809e4b06eb497832c33/t/53b129b8e4b0b3e1fc218d91/1404119492224/culture_bg_01.jpg

Comment: I did inspect the source and it is just confusing... there are so many divs and code I am not familiar with. I think what i want to do is fairly simple tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to address your questions thoroughly.

### **How to get an image to look exactly like the one under the navbar? (I have an image I want to use I just dont how to get it into my site under the navbar)**

This can be done in multiple ways. The website you linked did this by adding a `div` element with the `position: absolute` CSS property.

> This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to
>   literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use
>   the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the
>   location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next
>   parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no
>   such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element
>   itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.

So, when you apply `position: absolute` to an element, you are able to place it behind or above any other element too. I wouldn't recommend this approach. Below I have made 3 boxes, and I made the blue box have the `position:absolute` element.

```css
.box1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  }

.box2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:25px;
  }

.box3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:purple;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

**So how would I do it?** I would use a div element, and apply the `background` to it, much like how you did in your paste. Here's my shot at it:

```css
body{
        background-image: url("banner.png");
        width:100%;
}

.content{
    padding-top:100px;
    margin-top:128px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1024&text=Placeholder");
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height:500px;
}

.content .list{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    padding:5px;
    width:150px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
 
.container{
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
 
.header{
        background: gray;
        width:100%;
        top: 0;
        position:fixed;
}
 
.logo{
        /*float:left;
        margin-left: -250px;*/
        font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
 
a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color: white;
}
 
li{
        list-style: none;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        font-size:20px;
}
 
.nav{
       /*float:right;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="#">VectorGames</a></h1>

        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Arcade</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Puzzle</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Strategy</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="list">
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Abc</div>
        <div>Woohoo!</div>
        <p>All of this content is on top of the Placeholder background.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### **How to get it to auto respond like [the website above](http://www.vergecollective.com/) does?**

Responsive websites are a true must nowadays. People walk around with all sorts of electronics that can view websites. Notebooks, tablets, smartphones, we all want them to view our websites in a friendly way for the specific device watching.

In CSS, there is a solution to this called "Mediaqueries". Mediaqueries apply CSS **ONLY** **when** a specific screen width/height is being used by the user, when the user is using a smartphone/tablet in landscape mode or **until** a specific width/height is used. For example:

`@media screen and (min-width:1200px)` Means "If the browser window is a minimum of 1200px wide." The CSS would look like a nested block:

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugmgjna3/) shows a box that turns blue when you drag the window to under 500px.

---

### **and also how to make it so i can still add content to the page after that image in the banner area. Now i have it as the body background in css and that makes it so u cant add any content and be able to scroll.**

Just like my fiddle, you can add it as a child element of that `div` with the background. It will still be able to fulfill whatever you need it to do. You can do either that or add `position:absolute` to the element you want to float on top of other elements. The latter is not recommended since it creates a total mess if you don't have a good reason to use it.

Your pastebin unfortunately has some random `float` properties on the logo and the header, which places those floated elements outside of the screen. I assume this was not what you planned to do. My example above (the one with the div as a background) has your HTML and CSS code, with the float lines commented out.